# Limit number of retrieved items with scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

First of all I'd like to mention that I am a student and have little knowledge in this area.

I am trying to do one excercise in Python using scrapy to create a web crawler.

It works fine but one of the requirements is that I only retrieve the first 10 items, which I don't manage to achieve even using the custom setups:

```
custom_settings = {
    'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS': 1,
    'CONCURRENT_ITEMS' :1,
    'CLOSESPIDER_PAGECOUNT': 1,
    'CLOSESPIDER_ITEMCOUNT': 10
}
```

Could you please help me to find a solution to this?

Thanks in advance!

Code:

```py
import scrapy 
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class sjr_spider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = "sjr_spider"

    start_urls = [
        "https://www.scimagojr.com/journalrank.php?year=2017&area=1700"
    ]

    custom_settings = {
        'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS': 1,
        'CONCURRENT_ITEMS' :1,
        'CLOSESPIDER_PAGECOUNT': 1,
        'CLOSESPIDER_ITEMCOUNT': 10
    }

    def parse(self, response):

        for journal in response.xpath('//td[@class="tit"]/a/text()'):
            yield {
                'title': journal.extract()
            }
if __name__ == "__main__":

    process = CrawlerProcess({
        'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)',
        'DOWNLOAD_HANDLERS': {'s3': None},
         'LOG_ENABLED': True,

    })

    process.crawl(sjr_spider)
    process.start()
```

Comment: This is because the spider stops once 10 items are reached, but the requests in the queue will still be executed.

Is it necessary you only crawl 10 items, or could you also add in a counter to limit it to 10 items?

Comment: Use a couter and raise `CloseSpider` when the counter reaches 10. http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/faq.html?#how-can-i-instruct-a-spider-to-stop-itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Stan pointed out in the comments, your settings cause the spider to stop, but before the spider stops it processes the requests in the queue.

If you really need to drop anything over 10 items, you can [create an item pipeline](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html) that does that. It can count items and drop any item after the 10th.

You should still keep your `ITEM_CLOSESPIDER` setting, though, to ensure that the spider *starts stopping* after the 10th item.